# Why is a CoreData forceFetch required after a delete on the iPad but not the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-data

When the following code is run on the iPhone (ios 3.1) the count of fetched objects *after* the delete is one less than before the delete.  But on the iPad (ios 3.2) the count remains the same.   This inconsistency was causing a crash on the iPad because elsewhere in the code, soon after the delete, fetchedObjects is called and the calling code, trusting the count, attempts access to the just-deleted object's properties, resulting in a NSObjectInaccessibleException error (see below). A fix has been to use that commented-out call to performFetch, which when executed makes the second call to fetchObjects yield the same result as on the iPhone without it. My question is:  Why is the iPad producing different results than the iPhone?  This is the second of these differences that I've discovered and posted recently.

```
-(NSError*)deleteObject:(NSManagedObject*)mo;
{
NSLog(@"\n\nNum objects in store before delete: %i\n\n",
      [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count]);

    [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:mo];

    // Save the context.
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    }

//  [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];  // force a fetch

NSLog(@"\n\nNum objects in store after delete (and save): %i\n\n", 
      [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count]);

    return error;
}
```

(The full NSObjectInaccessibleException is: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSObjectInaccessibleException', reason: 'CoreData could not fulfill a fault for '0x1dcf90

Comment: Update: I have an interesting reply from someone on the Apple Dev forum. You experts might be interested.  I'm going to try this if I can figure out exactly what he's suggesting.  "Try adding an empty -controllerDidChangeContent: method to your FRC delegate.

- Ben"

Comment: What Ben suggested fixed the problem.  I simply added an empty -controllerDidChangeContent: method to my FRC delegate. Of course now I've gotta find out why. I asked Ben for more info and if he coughs it up you'll see it here.  Hopefully this question and answer is useful to others.

Comment: Just add the following lines to your FRC delegate:

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
}

Comment: Full explanation from Apple Dev forum: "The iPad is using iPhoneOS 3.2 while the iPhones 3.1.  There were a number of improvements to the NSFetchedResultsController in 3.2, but unfortunately, a side effect on the delegates' requirements to actually implement one (any one) of the delegate methods to get active change tracking."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding the following code to your FRC delegate will resolve this.

```
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller { }
```

Thanks to BenT at the Apple Dev forum for the answer (see my comments above). I asked him for an explanation of the fix and he said, "The iPad is using iPhoneOS 3.2 while the iPhones 3.1. There were a number of improvements to the NSFetchedResultsController in 3.2, but unfortunately, a side effect on the delegates' requirements to actually implement one (any one) of the delegate methods to get active change tracking." https://devforums.apple.com/message/221471#221471 (Hope this helps someone. The faq said it was ok to answer your own question in such cases)

Comment: This was driving me absolutely insane.  This exact same issue and fix also applies to iOS 4.0 (iPhone OS 4.0).  I just wish I had found this post 6 hours ago.

Comment: Wao thanks for this answer. I was getting mad with the problem as well. It helped me in iOS 4.3,

Answer (score 0):

Do keep in mind that the fetchedresultscontroller caches data to speed up its work. After deleting an object, you could also call + (void)deleteCacheWithName: to make sure the deleted object won't linger in the cache. That is, if you're not using delegate calls.

Answer (score 0):

To add a delegate method did not solve my problem. But I solved it by adding a forced performFetch after the deletion was finished. I also delete the cache before performing the fetch.

I'm on iOS 4.1.